# Creating docker secrets inside container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-secrets

My container needs to store the db credentials it receives via another service supplied by user. As the credentials will be supplied once by user, the container needs to persist these details so that it can restart and be able to make connections to db.

Is there a way I can create the docker secret at runtime from inside the container and use them everytime my container restarts?

Comment: If you need persistence then use a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Comment: @leopal right now, I am using volume to store.. however, since I am storing sensitive data, wanted to know how I can secure the data

Answer (score 1):

No, You can not create a secret inside the container, as container only consume the secret and administrator is supposed to create secrets.

your volume workaround may work, but it again not recommended to store secrets as any container launch with that volume will able to see these secret.

So the container should not store anything that supposed to be secret.

> You can use secrets to manage any sensitive data which a container
> needs at runtime but you don’t want to store in the image or in source
> control, such as:
>
> Usernames and passwords TLS certificates and keys SSH keys Other
>
> important data such as the name of a database or internal server
>
> Generic strings or binary content (up to 500 kb in size)

[engine-swarm-secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/)